# Possible to extend Max recording Length for a twilio conference?

Tags: twilio

The question has to do with recording of a CONFERENCE and NOT a CALL.

1. The max length of a call is 4 hours.
2. The max length of a recording is 4 hours.
3. There is NO max length of a conference call.

Since there is no max length of a conference call - there should not be a limit on the recording of the conference call either - are there any known work-arounds to get past the 4 hour limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to not use the record feature of the conference - but rather add a silent caller to dial in with record turned on and some silent sound on loop (to simulate active talking). This silent caller will need to be added every 4 hours (a few minutes before the 4 hour mark, so that one stays on after the other drops at the 4 hour mark) and multiple recordings will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

A recorded conference is a recorded call, so the maximum length of a recording still applies.

If you require longer conferences, then I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and explain why you need it. They may be able to help.

Comment: a conference is initiated at 00:00 where Caller 1 and 2 join at 00:00, caller 3 join at 03:00, caller 4 joins at 03:30. Caller 1 and 2 drop at 03:45.... the conference call will continue well beyond the 04:00 mark - so, the max length does not apply. Unless, recording is turned on... Verified it works this way.....

Comment: Sorry, you're right, the recording is the limiting factor here. As I said, it's best to contact support to see if they can do anything about it.

Comment: Thanks - but there isnt anything they can do about it, the 4 hour limit on calls and recordings is something that cannot be changed.

Comment: Ah, I see you found a workaround though. Good thinking!